# websites randomly don't work with Tor browser

Tags: 14.04, tor

I installed the Tor Browser Bundle with my ubuntu 14.04 and randomly can't access sites like bestbuy.com. some times it will work, but most of the time it will tell me I don't have permission to access this site on this server. I've searched every where for a solution but can't find anyone with a similar problem. If someone knows what's wrong with my tor browser bundle, or knows of a link with the same problem and solution, the help would be much appreciated

Comment: Not an answer but you might find this interesting regardless: http://blog.erratasec.com/2013/08/anonymity-smackdown-nsa-vs-tor.html#.VEGBQI_sPT8

Comment: so if tor isn't safe, then what is

Comment: security is relative.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message. Here is a [link on the Tor website](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/doc/ListOfServicesBlockingTor) which mentioned that BestBuy.com blocks Tor by default. BestBuy.com doesn't WANT you to visit their site through the Tor network. The reason it works sometimes, is probably because you got lucky and got a Tor server that wasn't blocked (yet).

Comment: That would explain that problem. I also can't access most .onion sites. When I emailed the tor browser help, I could access the site they included in the email and said if I can access that site but not others, then it's my problem and not theirs

Comment: @ahum12: Well, you could check if there is a newer version of the Tor Bundle available, but if not, you'll have to take it to [the Tor forum](http://torforum.org/) or somewhere else. I don't think it's a Linux problem (or Windows or OSX, for that matter) that AskUbuntu! can help you with, unfortunately.